# unset property in function also affecting passed variable

Tags: php, object

I have the following code

```
<?php
$foo[0] = new stdclass();
$foo[0]->foo = 'bar';
$foo[0]->foo2 = 'bar';
destroy_foo($foo);
var_dump ($foo);

function destroy_foo($foo) 
{
    unset($foo[0]->foo);
}
?>
```

The output is

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["foo2"]=> string(3) "bar" } }
```

I would expect `$foo[0]->foo` to still exist outside the function, but it doesn't. If I remove the properties and just use an array instead, it works. If I change the variable name inside the function, same problem. How can I use properties but make it work as expected?

Comment: because `objects are passed by reference by default` in php

Comment: that makes sense now, but any way to get around it? I need to unset it in the function, but need to use it later outside the function.

Comment: just store it in a temp variable and later reassign it or `clone` it

Answer (score 1):

What you see as an error is a PHP behaviour that's "working as expected": see the [objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) official guide.

It's not clear what you want to achieve with your code, but you should try to pass a [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) of your object to the function.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP Objects will only free their resources and trigger their __destruct method when *all* references are unsetted. So, to achieve your desire result, you have to 
assign null insteadof unsetting it.

$foo[0]->foo = null;